# Do hierarchical condensates yield instantaneous or sequential symmetry breaking?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, phase-transition, quantum-chromodynamics, symmetry-breaking

I am wondering whether the formation of a hierarchical [vacuum condensate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_expectation_value) yields an instantaneous or sequential symmetry breaking in a [cosmological phase transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_transition#Relevance_in_cosmology). Let me illustrate this question with the example of [QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics):

The cosmological phase transition of [chiral symmetry breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_symmetry_breaking) in QCD happens *instantaneously* at a temperature $T\sim \Lambda_{\rm QCD}$. In this transition, the [quark condensate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QCD_vacuum) $|\langle \bar{q}q\rangle|=v~{\rm diag}(1,1,1)$ forms, where $v\sim\Lambda_{\rm QCD}$. This condensate spontaneously breaks the approximate $SU(3)_L\times SU(3)_R$ flavor symmetry of the three lightest quarks $(u,d,s)$ down to $SU(3)_V$ and gives an equal mass contribution to these three quarks.

Now let us assume a hypothetical world in which a more general quark condensate,  e.g., $|\langle \bar{q}q\rangle|=v~{\rm diag}(a,b,c)$ with $a>b>c$, gives different contributions to the quark masses. (Such a condensate is of course not allowed in QCD since it would break the $SU(3)_V$ symmetry.)

Would such a hierarchical condensate still *instantaneously* break the original flavor symmetry $SU(3)\times SU(3)$ at a temperature $T\sim v\sim\Lambda_{\rm QCD}$? Or would it *sequentially* break the symmetry, e.g., down to $SU(2)^2\times U(1)$ at temperatures $T\sim a v$, and down to $U(1)^3$ at $T\sim b v$?

Comment: Could you perhaps give a reference where the idea of *instantaneous* symmetry breaking for the chiral symmetry comes from? It does not sound feasible.

Comment: So you are envisioning a mystery strong dynamics controlled by a theory dramatically different than a vector gauge theory like QCD, right? But then, why are you calling your freak condensate $v \sim \Lambda_{QCD}$? ***If*** this freak condensate emerged at two scales, then the chiral symmetry would break in two steps... but I hope you are not asking about theories that would actually do this...

Comment: @CosmasZachos: you are right that I do not consider the standard quark condensate of QCD. I still call it $v\sim\Lambda_{\rm QCD}$ for illustrative purposes. So you agree with the last sentence of my question above, i.e., that a non-unit condensate, such as $|\langle \bar{q}q\rangle|=v~{\rm diag}(1,2,3)$, would actually break the symmetry in two steps? And it would not be possible that such a condensate _instantaneously_ yields three different mass contributions?

Comment: Sure. Highly unconventional, but two dramatically different condensation scales would lead to mass disparities at different stages. I'm just reading off the premise for the condensate.